# Journey exit criteria to synchronized DE with 1:N doesn't work

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have set the exit criteria so the contact should exit if the value of `Application_Status__c` changes on the `Application__c_Salesforce` synchronized DE.

Contact can be multiple times in the `Application__c_Salesforce`, so I used `attribute-to-attribute` and compared the Contact data `Application ID` to the Journey data `Application ID`.

This way:
[image]

The contact doesn't exit on value change, and even if I set values not to match from prior to entry, it doesn't filter them at any point.
So it looks like there is no effect at all.

What am I missing?